# Ошибка конвертации py в exe

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

Пишу: `pyinstaller name.py` на что получаю ошибку

```
File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Новая папка\Python 3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "D:\Новая папка\Python 3\Scripts\calc.spec", line 18, in <module>
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 128, in assemble
    self.code_dict = {
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    key: strip_paths_in_code(code)
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 652, in strip_paths_in_code
    consts = tuple(
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 653, in <genexpr>
    strip_paths_in_code(const_co, new_filename)
  File "d:\новая папка\python 3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 660, in strip_paths_in_code
    return code_func(co.co_argcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize,
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Случайно у вас не стоит Python версии 3.8? Если ответ да то:

Необходимо обновить pyinstaller до совместимой версии, командой:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz
```